# Triggering multiple jenkins jobs based on the no of folder changes

Tags: python, jenkins, parameter-passing, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

We are trying to create a CI/CD for one of our clients. we have a requirement of creating one CI/CD pipeline for all the projects inside svn.

Poll Svn job will be polling on SVN for revision changes every one hour. As we have a robust folder structure, using python script or groovy script we are able to get the number of projects with changes since last poll.

Could you please let us know if it is possible to fire rest of the jobs in the pipeline for each of the changed projects dynamically.

```
eg: trunk --->CICD --> PROJECT1  
                   --> PROJECT2
                   --> PROJECT3
                   --> PROJECT4
```

If there is change in project 2 and project4, rest of the pipeline jobs should be triggered for project 2 and project4. Any suggestions are appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we achieved the same simply by using the parametrized build trigger and using parameter factory "Invoke one build per property file" option.

Answer (score 4):

I think what you require can be achieved quite easily with plain old groovy(if I got you right):

```
// I'm assuming here you somehow obtained a list of your projects...
def projects = ['project2', 'project4']

for (i = 0; i < projects.size(); i++) {
    build job: 'some-job-with-params', parameters: [string(name: 'myProject', value: 'project')]
}
```

In this example I pass the "project" name to a job that accepts this parameter and does something with it but it can be whatever you can think of.

Note I'm using traditional for loop here, view [these](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-examples/blob/master/docs/BEST_PRACTICES.md) guidelines to understand why.

I'm hopeful that this will assist you.

Comment: will it still ensure that that pipeline with upstream and downstream will be intact??

Comment: Not sure what u mean by that. Can u elaborate?